# How do i repeat a function until x happens?

Tags: html, autocomplete, repeater, repeat, dice

I am very VERY new to HTML and all programming so I apologize in advance if you find my layman's wording offensive.

Info: I'm making an auto-battle program for an RP group. a lot of my friends got bored because fighting usually goes
player:
"roll 1d20"
"6"
"Miss"
enemy:
"Roll 1d20"
"18"
"Hit"
"3d4"
"-10 dmg"

The program takes the player data, enemy data, etc, and runs through a bunch of rolls until one of them is dead.
I am unsure of how to make repeat statements like this (in HTML), how would I program it to roll until enough health is subtracted from either the player or imp?

Comment: I would recommend looking into JavaScript - this is a programming language supported by and built into all modern browsers, and used to provide interactability in webpges. Specifically, I'd recommend looking into `while` loops. These are constructs which do what you are asking for. However, since you are new to programming, I would recommend taking a look at some beginner JavaScript tutorials before continuing. What you are hoping to build could be quite complex without knowledge of JavaScriptor how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of coding. Your question is the spark that got most of us where we are today. There's a couple things you need to start with, HTML is a Markup language. This means it's not meant for writing logic but rather describing data in a way that can be consumed.

When we put together web projects we use a combination of HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. Each of these have a specific role in the website. Below is a short example of dice rolling, and hopefully will be enough to help you get started.

There are a million resources available, but the hardest part is knowing what you need to learn. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript) Has a great JavaScript resource, and is a nice place to start. If you prefer video, Youtube is overwhelmed with intro videos on JavaScript. Good luck!

```js
document.getElementById("d6").addEventListener("click", function() {
  rollDice(6)
})
document.getElementById("d20").addEventListener("click", function() {
  rollDice(20)
})


function rollDice(diceSize) {
  // Math.random() will give us a number between 0 and 1
  // Mutiply it by our dice size to make the number above 1
  // use '%' to perform a modulo operation - aka get the reminder from division. 
  // this forces the number to be between 1 and 6
  var diceRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * diceSize + 1 % diceSize);
  // Log to our console
  console.log(diceRoll);
  // Show a browser alert
  alert("Your roll: " + diceRoll);
}
```

```html
<button id="d6">d6</button>
<button id="d20">d20</button>
```